# Change constraint of label in custom table cell programmatically when phone goes into landscape. ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, size-classes

I have a label in a custom cell and it currently has a width constraint of 150. When the phone goes into landscape orientation, I would like to increase the width constraint to 300. Then of course change it back to 150 when phone goes back to portrait. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Use auto layout constraints

Comment: I am using auto layout constraints. I need to add one constraint programmatically.

Comment: You can change the width by changing constraint's constant variable programmatically

Comment: I'm aware of this but I don't know how to do it. I also want to do this when phone is in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine **Size Classes** to achieve this. You can set up 300 on `AnyWidth CompactHeight`(landscape mode for iPhone) and set up 150 on `CompactWidth RegularHeight`(portrait mode for iPhone).

Enable **Size Classes** in the **Interface Builder Document**. Then, you will need to configure based on on different size classes. More information, you can find it online: [Adaptive Layout from Ray Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

Another approach will be: changing the constraint's `constant` value based on different mode of the screen. You will need to reference the constraint as `IBOutlet` and then change it programatically. But, we don't suggest to do so because Apple is tended to have different size of device and it's better to work on layout by combining **Auto Layout** and **Size Classes**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense.

Comment: Make it up and like if you think so